# Process php array without php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function that receives a PHP array as a response from an API. How do I process it without using PHP as my server runs on flask and I do not want to host another PHP file unless absolutely necessary. Is it possible to convert the array to json without php's json_encode() function?
The array response is given below.

```
Total Costs
Array
(
    [metadata] => Array
        (
            [material] => ABS
            [color] => #000000
            [infillPercentage] => 30
            [layerHeight] => 0.254
            [supportRemoval] => false
            [vaporPolishing] => false
            [shipping] => delivery
            [rushPrinting] => true
        )

    [totalWeight] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 19.8
            [unit] => grams
        )

    [totalTime] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 3489
            [unit] => seconds
        )

    [costs] => Array
        (
            [printTime] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 3.88
                    [calculation] => 3489 seconds * (1 hour)/(60*60 seconds) * $4.00 USD/hour
                    [unit] => USD
                )

            [material] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 3.96
                    [calculation] => 19.80 grams * 0.20 USD/g
                    [unit] => USD
                )

            [delivery] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 6.00
                    [calculation] => 5.80 USD base + 19.80 grams * 0.01 USD/g
                    [unit] => USD
                )

        )

    [subtotal] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 13.84
            [calculation] => 3.88 USD printTime + 3.96 USD material + 6.00 USD delivery
            [unit] => USD
        )  

    [total] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 13.84
            [calculation] => 13.84 subtotal
            [unit] => USD
    )

)
API Response
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [estimatedCost] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 7.84
                [unit] => USD
                [calculation] => 0.97 hours * $4.00/hour + 19.80 grams * $0.20/gram
            )

        [filamentUsed] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 19.8
                [unit] => grams
                [calculation] => (1.75mm/2)^2 * 3.1416 * 7917mm * 1cm^3/1000mm^3 * 1.04g/cm^3
            )

        [gCodeLink] => http://www.3dpartprice.com/gCodeOutput/CactusBody.stl.gcode
        [printDuration] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 3489
                [unit] => seconds
                [formatted] => 58 minutes, 9 seconds
            )

        [sliceDuration] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 0.72
                [unit] => seconds
            )

        [slicer] => cura
        [stlFileLink] => http://www.3dpartprice.com/stlUploads/CactusBody.stl
        [stlFilename] => CactusBody.stl
        [stlFilesize] => 29484
        [stlTriangleCount] => 588
        [stlVolume] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 30.25
                [unit] => cm
                [formatted] => cm^3
            )

    )

)
```

EDIT: Below is the form used to call the API

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formprint" action="http://3dpartprice.com/3dpartpricelib/api-caller.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="material" value="ABS">  ABS <br>
  <input type="radio" name="material" value="PLA">  PLA
  <!-- ABS PLA  -->
  <input type='radio' name='color' value='#000000'> White <br>
  <input type='radio' name='color' value='#FFFFFF'> Black <br>
  <!-- value - 000000 or FFFFFF      class - ABS or PLA -->
  <input type="text" name="layerHeight" value="0.254">
  <!-- 0.1 to 0.4 -->
  <input type="text" name="infillPercentage" value="30">
  <!-- (0 to 100%) -->
  <input type="file" name="stlFiles[]" multiple>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe if you showed us an example of the array and the code we could be more helpful

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: try JSON.parse()

Comment: @vSugumar a php array (as printed, e.g., by `print_r`) doesn't even remotely look like a json array.

Comment: @vSugumar That parses a JSONString into a javascript data type. It wont work if this array is actually a PHP array

Comment: My bad. It is a generic array but I'll edit the question

Comment: I thought the api returns json

Comment: How did you print the response?

Comment: the API returns me this as string

Comment: Is there an option on the API that you can set to get JSON as the response

Comment: It would be useful to see the code, specially the code you used to output the response from the API

Comment: The API returns a string like a PHP array? Really? Sounds very odd to build an API with that kind of output.

Comment: That's the problem here. The API isn't well built but we have no option but to use it. We need to parse this output to obtain the amount of filament used and the print duration

Comment: But if the output is a string of an array you can't even load it in PHP either. My solution would be to not use that API.

Comment: Is it possible to use Regular Expressions to parse it?

Comment: First we need to see the actual output. I tried using the page you link to but I don't get any API response. Can you link to an or post the actual output. EDIT; got it to work. Bloddy h*&$+ , what did that developer think of? Can't you ask if he/she can include an Json?

Comment: The above posted output is the actual output. To recreate the output just upload an stl file in http://3dpartprice.com/3dpartpricelib/api-caller.php and submit query

Comment: @Andreas I see that you understand my pain now. I don't know whether the developer will respond. But he does provide the source code of the API [here](http://3dpartprice.com/3dpartpricelib/3dpartpricelib-0.1.4.zip). To run this code I'll need a full fledged server so I wanted to use their server.

Comment: Yes I saw that. I believe it's better to ask the owner of the page to include a Json. Trying to parse that is going to be a lot of work. If it was an var_export you could (if you dare) use an eval of the response in PHP, but that is risky.

Comment: @Andreas I think we'll do that. In the meanwhile, we're thinking of hard parsing the output using regex. Hope it works. Ty for your help

Comment: The owner did a change 12 months ago and this change is very very simple to do, just ask for a `echo json_encode($array);`, after all he got 26 GB of we space to use.

Comment: @Andreas, yeah true. But we figured out how to regex our requirements, so it's cool. Might email him later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did eventually solve it using Hard regexing the required things. Thought I'll answer it if anyone came across the same API and the same troubles.

```
function parsePrintInfo(str){
  var re = /\[filamentUsed\]/g;
  var re2 = /\[printDuration\]/g;
  var grams='';
  var duration='';
  var price='';

  while ((match = re.exec(str)) !=null){
    grams = grams + "weight : " + str.substr(match.index+74,10)+" grams <br>";
    document.getElementById("view_weight").innerHTML =grams;
  }
  while ((match = re2.exec(str)) !=null){
    duration = duration + "duration : " + str.substr(match.index+74,10)+" seconds <br>";
    price = price + (parseFloat(str.substr(match.index+74,10).trim())*144/3600).toString() + " INR <br>";
    finalPrice = Math.round((parseFloat(str.substr(match.index+74,10).trim())*144/3600))+finalPrice;
    document.getElementById("view_time").innerHTML =duration;
    document.getElementById("view_price").innerHTML =price;
  }
  $("#finalPrice").html("<small>Approximate Cost<br></small>Rs. " + finalPrice.toString());
}
```

Now, this is a really bad way to be solving this problem and we did this only after realising we had no choice but to use this workaround. This basically means we can only use this answer for our particular case. But it can be modified to work for other cases too.